# <List> of objects with functions, how to call those functions?

Tags: java, list, collections, arraylist

Im approaching  like I do just a regular Array, so that may be part of my confusion.

Say I have an object

```
class myObject {
    public void func() {//... do stuff...}
}
```

and I make a List of these objects

```
public List<MyObject> objects;
MyObject object1 = new MyObject();
objects.add(object1);
```

Is there a way to call func()?

I have tried

```
objects.func();
```

With an array it would be just a for loop, something like

```
myarray[0].func();
```

Stumped.

Comment: C'mon! `objects.get(0).func()`...

Comment: well Ill be damned. Thank you.

Comment: Please post actual code. Not only isn't the snippit you post invalid, even if it were you're never instantiating the list. If you were to, you'd need to iterate though it to find the object you're interested in (or, if you simply want to call a method on every one ... do that).

Comment: I suggest you to look at iterators in Java

Comment: Thats where I was. Would help if I was at home using Eclipse instead of notepad here, code completion would have saved me the embarrasment. :-P

Answer (score 2):

This is a straightforward case for the Java [enhanced for loop:](http://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with)

```
for (MyObject obj: objects) {
    obj.func();
}
```

Comment: The loop should just be a for loop, not a foreach loop (foreach isn't a keyword in Java).

Comment: Silly me - I've been writing too much C# lately :)  Fixed

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a simple for loop:

```
for (MyObject m: objects)
    m.myFunc();
```

Or, with a traditional for loop:

```
for (int k = 0; k < objects.size(); k++)
    objects.get(k).myFunc();
```

Hope this helps!